# PowerApps form - Change fields' error message color - Red is not 508 compliant

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

As a general question, my client is concerned that the Required field error message (trying to submit a form without required fields populated) and field border color is Red - and not 508 compliant.

I would like to modify this to highlight the border as yellow, and the same with the error message.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you using Power Apps customized SharePoint list form?

Comment: It's a Canvas app, although it's data source is a Sharepoint list (edit form on main screen)

Comment: ok. check my response below. Let me know if it works for you to change the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Form control in Power Apps, you have the data card controls for each field inside the form control.

You will have your input field controls (like text input, date, drop down controls) and error message label control inside each of those data cards.

For example:

[image]

So, you will have to change the colors for each input fields controls and the error message label control separately.

**Changing border color of input controls**:

1. Select the input field control (generally name starts with `DataCardValue`) and unlock it to change the properties:

   [image]
2. Keep the input field control selected and change the `BorderColor` property like:

   ```
   If(IsBlank(Parent.Error), Parent.BorderColor, Color.Yellow)
   ```

   [image]

**Changing color of error message label controls**:

1. Select the error message control and unlock the data card (if not unlocked already)
2. Change the `Color` property like:

   [image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!!